# Left child's right child compared to "grandfather"

Tags: binary-tree, parent-child

Suppose we have a node's left child in a binary tree.

Can the right child of the previously mentioned left child have a greater key-value than his parent's parent?

Comment: Is it a BST, or just a binary tree?

Comment: any binary tree

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can put any value you want in any node of the tree.  It's a free country.

Now, if you want it to be a usable Binary Search Tree, then, No. Every node in the left subtree must be less than the parent, (and every node in the right subtree must be greater than it).  It won't matter if it's the child's left or right child. They are all on the left side of the grandparent, so they must be less.